# Temperature Conversion using OR operator in python

Tags: python

i tried to use this code to make a simple temp converter between Celcius and Farenheit....My code :

```
value=raw_input("Temperature Reading= ")
check=value[-1]
c=int(value[:-1])
if check =='c' or 'C':
    print (9*c/5)+32,'F'
if check =='f' or 'F':
    print 5*(c-32)/9,'C'

raw_input("Press <Enter> to exit!")
```

the problem with this is that if the user inputs for example 50f it prints both of them in the 'if' functions. I need to correct it. thanks :)

Comment: The first thing  that comes to mind is to use ```regex``` to split the letters from numbers.  That's probably the most general/robust way to do it.

Comment: i have no idea of such complex functions '^.^ my bad i know....

Comment: We get this question daily. `or` doesn't work that way, use `if check =='c' or check == 'C':` or `if check in 'cC':` or `if check.lower() == 'c':`...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich thanks i think i got it xD so OR doesnt work that way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your checks are not correct

```
if check =='f' or 'F':
```

should be

```
if check == 'f' or check == 'F':
```

Idem for the other 'C' one.

Also nicer is:

```
if check in ['c', 'C']:
```

Or

```
if check.lower() == 'c':
```